# MediaCodec simultaneous encoding and decoding

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec

I am trying to apply effects to the frames of a video using the GPU and then to re-encode those frames into a new result video.

In the interest of performance I have implemented the following flow:

There are 3 different threads, each with it's own OpenGL context. These contexts are set up in such a way that they share textures between them.

**Thread 1** extracts frames from the video and holds them in the GPU memory as textures, similar to **[this](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ExtractMpegFramesTest_egl14.java.txt)** example.

**Thread 2** processes the textures using a modified version of GPUImage that also outputs textures in the GPU memory.

Finally, **thread 3** writes the textures obtained from thread 2 into a new video file similar to the method described **[here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java)**

Frame order is maintained using queues between threads 1 and 2, and threads 2 and 3. Textures are deleted from memory manually **after** they are used for processing / writing.

The whole point of this flow is to separate each process in hopes that the final performance will be that of the slowest of the 3 threads.

**THE PROBLEM:**

The final video is 90% black frames, only some of them being correct.

I have checked the individual results of extraction, and processing and they work as expected. Also note that the 3 components described in the 3 threads work just fine together in a single thread.

I have tried to synchronise thread 1 and thread 3, and after adding an extra 100ms sleep time to thread 1 the video turns out just fine, with maybe 1 or 2 black frames. Seems to me like the two instance of the decoder and encoder are unable to work simultaneously.

I will edit this post with any extra requested details.

Answer (score 3):

Sharing textures between OpenGL ES contexts requires some care.  The way it's implemented in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "show + capture camera" Activity is broken; see [this issue](https://github.com/google/grafika/issues/36) for details.  The basic problem is that you essentially need to issue memory barriers when the texture is updated; in practical terms that means issuing `glFinish()` on the producer side and, and re-binding the texture on the consumer side, and doing all of this in `synchronized` blocks.

Your life will be simpler (and more efficient) if you can do all of the GLES work on a single thread.  In my experience, having more than one GLES context active at a time is unwise, and you'll save yourself some pain by finding an alternative.

You probably want something more like this:

- Thread #1 reads the file and feeds frames into a MediaCodec decoder.  The decoder sends the output to a SurfaceTexture Surface.
- Thread #2 has the GLES context.  It created the SurfaceTexture that thread #1 is sending the output to.  It processes the images and renders the output on the Surface of a MediaCodec encoder.
- Thread #3, which created the MediaCodec encoder, sits waiting for the encoded output.  As output is received it's written to disk.  Note that the use of MediaMuxer can stall; see [this blog post](http://blog.horizon.camera/post/134263616000/optimizing-mediamuxers-writing-speed) for more.

In all cases, the only communication between threads (and, under the hood, processes) is done through Surface.  The SurfaceTexture and MediaCodec instances are created and used from a single thread; only the producer endpoint (the Surface) is passed around.

One potential trouble point is with flow control -- SurfaceTextures will drop frames if you feed them too quickly.  Combining threads #1 and #2 might make sense depending on circumstances.

Comment: Hello @fadden and thank you for your response. My original solution would use a single thread and work nicely, it was however not fast enough.

I am not sure I understand the importance of the SurfaceTexture. At this time i copy the resulting decoder textures into a new texture i create with GLES20.glGenTextures, and keep it's handle so i can use it later.

Also, how exactly am i supposed to use one context across three threads? Decoding, processing and encoding all require a current openGL context.

Comment: SurfaceTexture takes whatever is drawn on a Surface and wraps it into a GLES "external" texture. That's what your linked example (ExtractMpegFramesTest) uses. What was the bottleneck when using a single thread? i.e. what's the slowest part of your pipeline? You should only need to use GLES from thread #2 in the above scheme.

Comment: The frame extraction part seems to be the slowest, that is why i figured that i could give it more time to extract while the processing was being done. You are right about the linked example, however in the interest of saving time, i copy the extracted texture to a new texture managed by me, in order to pass it quicker to phase 2.

Comment: Decoding the video should not be the slowest part. One common mistake is to try to feed a single frame to the decoder at a time, rather than feeding frames as quickly as possible to keep the decoder fed. The decoding is being done by the hardware codec, managed by a separate process, and involved multiple buffers, so all of the effort is already overlapped. The systrace tool is the best way to examine bottlenecks in code like this (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html).

Comment: I use the decoder on a frame by frame basis. I request a time from it and seek to the nearest previous keyframe then feed it until i receive the frame with the presentation time i requested. I'm using the decoder like this as the idea is to reencode to 30fps video, regardless of the original video's framerate.

Comment: That explains the poor performance -- there's latency in the encoding process, and you're paying the cost of decoding frames multiple times. You'd probably do better with a single-threaded approach that streamed the video through in one pass (like the DecodeEditEncode test on bigflake). That does require changing the logic from, "decide what I need next and find it" to "see what's coming next and decide what to do with it".

Comment: So what you are suggesting is i decode all the frames and decide if i keep them or not based on presentation time,  correct? And if i were to use this approach  but try to maintain the threaded logic?  Would this solve the black frames issue?

Comment: I'm guessing that the black frames are due to sharing textures across EGL contexts in different threads without the EGL/GLES equivalent of memory barriers. Changing the thread arrangement so that you have only one EGL context will remove any glitches associated with that issue.

Comment: Isn't it impossible to make one context current on multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: Yes... that's why it's only used on one thread. Bear in mind that a Surface is a cross-process end point, and that decoding and encoding video doesn't involve the GPU.